# SATA Multipliers Power

Tags: sata

I am currently looking forward to buy a SATA multiplier so that I can have multiply SSD drives using a single SATA port. My question is regarding the product bellow product.

http://uk.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/2-Port-eSATA-ExpressCard-Drive-Controller-Card~ECESATA22

I can see that there is only the data ports but will also that power up the drive?

Comment: Yes I can! I have done my research, this is why am asking this question.

Comment: My question is not about whether I can. Because I know I can. My question is a about a specific product.It would be really good if you read the question first.

Comment: @Ramhound With a SATA port multiplier you can have up to 15 SATA devices connected to a single SATA port

Comment: But the device isn't even a SATA multipler though.  The product will only be able to power 2 eSATA devices.  The enclosure that was linked to uses USB 3 to power the device, I see no evidence it's a eSATA multiplier though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Serial ATA port multiplier is a device that allows multiple SATA devices to be connected to a single SATA host port. Many common controllers do not support this feature, as it is not a requirement for a SATA controller.

First off, I am assuming you are using a laptop, since the product you linked is an ExpressCard, typically found in laptops.  Although, it would work on a desktop with an ExpressCard slot.

The product you linked is not SATA, its eSATA.  That would mean you would need an [eSATA enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005B5G4S6) to hold the two drives and provide power.  It says right in the description it is a port multiplier, so it would work.

FYI eSATA and SATA are technically the same, its just eSATA has a different connector for external use.

Comment: Note, the linked product supports port multipliers, but it does not indicate that it is a port multiplier itself. I would expect it to have two separate SATA channels.

Comment: @DarthAndroid Hmm, I reread the product... it doesnt *specifically* state it is a port multiplier.  However, I definitely inferred it from the "StarTech.com Advantage".  My gut feeling it is...  All he has to do is ask them to find out for sure.